# ESP-IDF: idf.py build fails with cmake error (unknown cmake command idf_component_register)

Tags: c, cmake, ninja, esp-idf

idf.py build consistently fails on my windows install of esp-idf, I installed it using the tools provided in espressif's documentation, here are the logs:

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyCJ0.png)

I tried reinstalling to no avail. Other than that I don't know what to do exactly since it always just worked when I used it on linux

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the error message to be in the question post itself as **text**, not linked as *image*. Please, (re-)read [ask] and edit your question post accordingly. Also, according to the output, you are runing `cmake` from the wrong directory. Most likely you somehow deviate from the documentation. But since you don't show what you actually doing, we cannot point you to a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As you are use old SDK version please re-clone new sdk and compile it will work fine.

I suggest you to use V4.4 as this sdk is more stable then V5